# TextFormField value gets clear when keyboard dismiss

Tags: flutter, keyboard

TextFormField value gets clear when keyboard dismiss. I am saving all values in register_request_model. When I scroll the screen and press the done button from the keyboard few TextFormField gets clear. This approach is working fine at my Login screen where I am using only two TextFormFields. I am also using Stateful widget.

```
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/register_request_model.dart';
import '../models/genderModel.dart';
import '../widgets/cusotm_radio.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';


class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/register';

  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {

  final _emailFocus = FocusNode();
  final _addressFocus = FocusNode();
  final _phoneNumberFocus = FocusNode();
  final _passwordFocus = FocusNode();
  final _cityFocus = FocusNode();

  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  DateTime _selectDate = DateTime.now();
  String _date = "Not set";

  List<Gender> genders = new List<Gender>();

  var _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
      name: '',
      email: '',
      address: '',
      phonenumber: '',
      city: '',
      dob: '',
      gender: '',
      password: '');
  var _initValues = {
    'name': '',
    'email': '',
    'address': '',
    'phonenumber': '',
    'city': '',
    'dob': '',
    'gender': '',
    'password': '',
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    genders.add(new Gender("Male", MdiIcons.genderMale, false));
    genders.add(new Gender("Female", MdiIcons.genderFemale, false));
    genders.add(new Gender("Others", MdiIcons.genderTransgender, false));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailFocus.dispose();
    _addressFocus.dispose();
    _phoneNumberFocus.dispose();
    _passwordFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool validateEmail(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    return (!regex.hasMatch(value)) ? false : true;
  }

  Future<void> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime(2000,1),
        firstDate: DateTime(1960, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2004));
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectDate)
      setState(() {
        _selectDate = picked;
        _date = '${picked.year} - ${picked.month} - ${picked.day}';
      });
  }

  Widget addHeightSpace25(){
    return SizedBox(height: 25.0);
  }

  Widget addHeightSpace10(){
    return SizedBox(height: 10.0);
  }

  Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _form.currentState.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }

    if(_date.startsWith('Not')){
     showToast("Please select date!");
    }

    print(getSelectedGender());
    if(getSelectedGender()==null){
      showToast("Please select gender!");
    }

    _form.currentState.save();

    print(_registerRequest.email);

    //setState(() {});
  }

  void showToast(String msg){

    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: msg,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 14.0
    );
  }

  String getSelectedGender(){
    var val= "";
    for(int i=0 ; i < genders.length; i++){
      if(genders[i].isSelected){
        val = genders[i].name;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(val.isEmpty){
      return null;
    }else{
      return val;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Registration'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0, 20.0, 20),
          child: Form(
            key: _form,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['name'],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter valid name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _initValues['name'] = 'zoraiz';
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: value,
                      email: _registerRequest.email,
                      address: _registerRequest.address,
                      phonenumber: _registerRequest.phonenumber,
                      city: _registerRequest.city,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: _registerRequest.password,
                    );
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_emailFocus);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['email'],
                  focusNode: _emailFocus,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter email address!';
                    }

                    if (!(validateEmail(value))) {
                      return 'Invalid Email';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: _registerRequest.name,
                      email: value,
                      address: _registerRequest.address,
                      phonenumber: _registerRequest.phonenumber,
                      city: _registerRequest.city,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: _registerRequest.password,
                    );
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_addressFocus);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['address'],
                  focusNode: _addressFocus,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter address!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: _registerRequest.name,
                      email: _registerRequest.email,
                      address: value,
                      phonenumber: _registerRequest.phonenumber,
                      city: _registerRequest.city,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: _registerRequest.password,
                    );
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_phoneNumberFocus);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['phonenumber'],
                  focusNode: _phoneNumberFocus,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'PhoneNumber'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter phone number';
                    }
                    if(value.length < 12){
                      return 'Incorrect phone number';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: _registerRequest.name,
                      email: _registerRequest.email,
                      address: _registerRequest.address,
                      phonenumber: value,
                      city: _registerRequest.city,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: _registerRequest.password,
                    );
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_cityFocus);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['city'],
                  focusNode: _cityFocus,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter city';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: _registerRequest.name,
                      email: _registerRequest.email,
                      address: _registerRequest.address,
                      phonenumber: _registerRequest.phonenumber,
                      city: value,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: _registerRequest.password,
                    );
                  },

                ),
                addHeightSpace25(),
                Text(
                  'Date',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
               addHeightSpace10(),
                FlatButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black45,
                        width: 1,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    selectDate(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.date_range,
                                    size: 18.0,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    " $_date",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 14.0),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "  Change",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 14.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                addHeightSpace25(),
                Text(
                  'Select Gender',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                ),
                addHeightSpace10(),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 84,
                          child:  ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                              itemCount: genders.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return InkWell(
                                  splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      genders
                                          .forEach((gender) => gender.isSelected = false);
                                      genders[index].isSelected = true;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: CustomRadio(genders[index]),
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5.0,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  initialValue: _initValues['password'],
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Password must be at-least 6 characters';
                    }
                    if (value.length < 6) {
                      return 'Password must be at-least 6 characters';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _registerRequest = RegisterRequestModel(
                      name: _registerRequest.name,
                      email: _registerRequest.email,
                      address: _registerRequest.address,
                      phonenumber: _registerRequest.phonenumber,
                      city: _registerRequest.city,
                      dob: _registerRequest.dob,
                      gender: _registerRequest.gender,
                      password: value,
                    );
                  },
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    _saveForm();
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                Container(
                  height: 45,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 50, 0),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _saveForm();
                    },
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text("SIGN UP".toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 35,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Already have an account?',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'SignIn',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                              fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try assigning a controller to each text field?

Comment: @MagnusW no I didn't use but my above mention approach is working fine at my Login Screen. This issue comes when I scroll down the screen and then press done.

Comment: @MagnusW controller option is also not working.

Answer (score 6):

After spending a lot of time I reached out When scrolled back into the view TextFormField that was wrapped under the listview loses its state. SingleChildScrollView works for me.